# Not too much run it on

Tags: meaning

> Mother has the house in Wallingford,” Marion said, “and **not too much to run it on,** when Fred’s school bills have been paid. I had a little capital of my own, enough to keep me while I was learning to make a living, so I decide to come to London and train for a secretary’s job. I took this place we’re going to, and started a course at Needham’s.
>
> — *The Little Mystery* by E.C. Bentley (my emphasis)

What's the meaning of 'not too much to run it on'?
"Nothing much left" or something else?

Comment: *run*: manage (the finances of.) To run the house is (to pay for the expenses of) maintaining the household. The house was not so big that the income from it could take care of running the household.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase “and not too much to run it on..." speaks of a time when one had an allowance, or the capital/interest of an estate.  Typically, a trust is either lifetime, age-limited, till marriage, or subject to fixed funds, and is used for diurnal expenses.  A trust is typically managed by a lawyer/banker, and is often generational -The Kennedy family still lives off the trust established by Joe Kennedy, Sr.

In the case of the speaker "not too much to run it on" means very little, other than, one's spending rises to their income